# Can PostgreSQL save a query result in a variable?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to change the name of a database to include todays date and a comment in PostgreSQL using a query.

So far I have managed to change the name to include the date

```
\c postgres

SELECT 
    pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM 
    pg_stat_activity 
WHERE 
    -- don't kill my own connection!
    pid <> pg_backend_pid()
    -- don't kill the connections to other databases
    AND datname = 'sdm'
    ;

DO $$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format ('ALTER DATABASE %I RENAME TO %I_%s', 'sdm', 'sdm', to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')::TEXT);
END
$$;
```

and a query to show the comment in data output.

```
SELECT pg_catalog.shobj_description(d.oid, 'pg_database') AS "Description"
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_database d
WHERE  datname = 'sdm';
```

Is it possible to save the data output of the comment into a variable and use it to rename the database?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a variable, since you can use a subquery almost anywhere in an SQL statement:

```
EXECUTE
   format (
      'ALTER DATABASE %I RENAME TO %I',
      'sdm',
      (SELECT ...) || '_' ||
         to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')::TEXT
   );
```